# Connect to external TV without main screen

Tags: macos, display, screen

I have a Macbook Pro 13 "(late 2009) with a screen that just stopped working.

In the technical assistance they told me that the problem would be the logic board or the display, any of them quite expensive to fix.

So, I bought an mini display port to HDMI adapter to connect to my TV until I buy a new laptop.

The problem is that it did not automatically detect the tv and as I cannot see the monitor, I cannot configure it.
Is there anyway for me to configure my laptop to show the screen on the TV just with the keyboard or by VoiceOver (not sure how that works)

thank you

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you need to reset the PRAM/NVRAM which contains the resolution information.

Here is the apple page (instructions) on doing it.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379